# In python 27 how do I use **kwargs to define member variables in a class?

Tags: class, python-2.7, member, keyword-argument

I am looking to define the member variables of the object class using ** in Python27 but when I run the following code it doesn't work.

```
class Object:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for k, v in kwargs.iteritems():
            self.k = v
            print str(k) + " " + str(v) + " " + str(self.k)
        print str(self.x)
        print str(self.y)
        print self.name

Player = Object(x=10, y=10, name="Player")
```

I know exactly what the problem is because when I call

```
print str(self.k)
```

it prints the last entry in the loop. So I am PRETTY sure what is happening is that when k is key 'name' and v is the value "Player" it is assigning "Player" to a new member variable 'self.k' instead of 'self.name' but I have no idea what to do about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set member variable with name known only in runtime you should use [`setattr()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr) builtin function.

> `setattr(object, name, value)`
>
> This is the counterpart of `getattr()`. The
>   arguments are an object, a string and an arbitrary value. The string
>   may name an existing attribute or a new attribute. The function
>   assigns the value to the attribute, provided the object allows it. For
>   example, `setattr(x, 'foobar', 123)` is equivalent to `x.foobar = 123`.

In your case:

```
for k, v in kwargs.iteritems():
    setattr(self, k, v)
```

Comment: { ^o^} IT'S BEAUTIFUL! TY! :D